# How to use k380-function-keys-conf

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, logitech

I am trying to change the default setting for the function keys on k380 Bluetooth keyboard.

They are currently working as a special keys to control such as audio volume, unless I press "fn" key at the same time.
I searched around and found another thread in this site.

[Logitech K380 bluetooth keyboard - make function keys default](https://askubuntu.com/questions/699138/logitech-k380-bluetooth-keyboard-make-function-keys-default)

I managed to download
k380-function-keys-conf at GitHub.

The files consiste of the following 4 files.
LICENCE, README.md, buils.sh, k380_conf.c

I read README as well as the links included in README,
but still got no idea how to use buils.sh, k380_conf.c
to change k380's default function key setting.

I am using Mint Cinnamon 18 which is based on Ubuntu 16.04.
I am not an absolute beginner but not an advanced user either.

If anyone can help me, it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please don't post multiple answers documenting your progress like this. [ubuntu.se] is strictly a Q&A site and not a discussion forum. You might want to take the [tour] or read our [help] for details. It's great that you're willing to put in the effort to answer your own question (and thanks), but please gather everything up in a *single*, complete answer and post that. Any detail you've discovered after asking your question should go into the question itself (without "edit" or anything like that, just rewrite it) and only the final solution should be an answer. Welcome to the site!

Comment: I found a solution. 1) Install a tool for compiling:[sudo apt-get install build-essential]  2) Go to directory where the file was extracted: [cd Desktop/k380-function-keys-conf-master] 3) Type [./build.sh] This should create a new file called k380_conf 5) The next part is rather tricky. In the terminal type: [sudo ./k380_conf -d /dev/hidrawX -f on] Replace X with the hidraw number for k380.

Comment: There are more than one way to find out this number, but I found it is much quicker to try out from the number 0 till you hit the right one. If the hidraw number is wrong you will get the following error message: The given device is not a supported Logitech keyboard: Operation not permitted 
If the number is correct, you will get yet another error message: write: 0 were written instead of 7. But it is in fact, working.

Comment: (Following to the terdon's advice, I deleted and edited my comments. I hope this eliminate the clutter I created.)

Answer (score 0):

if you want, im created a applet for ubuntu based in code https://github.com/jergusg/k380-function-keys-conf

https://github.com/carlossil01/k380-function-keys-conf-applet

thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I will study it and report the outcome here.

Comment: This is what I did to make this Python script work: 1) Edit  applet.py file to reflect the current  hidraw. Open the file with text editor and find the following line: command = "./k380_conf -d /dev/hidraw1 -f %s" % action 2) Change hidraw1 to whatever the correct number. (Mine was hidraw5.) 3) Edit confid.py. Find a line for sudo password. Replace it with actual password. 4)In terminal, type python applet.py This should bring a small icon on the tool bar to easily toggle fn lock key.

Comment: To make this applet to start automatically at booting, follow the instruction here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/816843/how-to-auto-start-python-script-for-kb380-function-key-applet?noredirect=1#comment1237013_816843