# Is there any way to enable a Num. Lock function in the Logitech K380 and use the "789uiojklm" keys as num. pad in the keyboard itself?

Tags: keyboard, logitech, numlock, numpad

I wondered if this was possible for the K380 model by any official support tool or hacking it somehow, and making it work in any device, or if it's a hardware-wise limitation issue. Thank you!

The main motivation is that I want to be able to use the ASCII encoding as I rely quite regularly on it for calling a number of special characters. If weren't possible to activate the requested function, do you know any curious, efficient workaround to use those kind of symbols?

Maybe trying some sort of solutions as proposed in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/699138/logitech-k380-bluetooth-keyboard-make-function-keys-default/1468176#1468176) topic (?):

- [Solaar app](https://github.com/pwr-Solaar/Solaar)
- [Jergusg solution](https://github.com/jergusg/k380-function-keys-conf) for function keys configuration.