# i3wm: How can I switch Fn Keys on a Logitech K600 TV Keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, logitech, wireless-keyboards

> My System: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Updated)
>
> Window Manager/Desktop Environment: i3WM

The Logitech K600 TV Keyboard works flawlessly in my Laptop for the majority of the tasks, the features of this keyboard are awesome as it has 3 dedicated keys which I use for switching between the computer (using wireless dongle) and 2 Samsung Galaxy Tab devices (bluetooth connected).

## The problem

The 3 dedicated keys I mentioned before, are the same keys used for <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>F3</kbd> which I should trigger by pressing a key combination with the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key.

### Expected solution

I would like to switch the usage of the dedicated keys in order to make them trigger the default <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>F3</kbd> keys *whith no need to use the <kbd>Fn</kbd> in a combination.

### Please consider

1. I am using i3WM, no desktop environment, no other window manager.
2. A BIOS based solution will only work for the physical keyboard on
   the laptop, not for the wireless keyboard.
3. I have requested Logitech's support via support ticket, and they
   guided me to this page:
   https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025297893 which
   provides a list of resources made for Windows or MacOS. There's no a
   Linux solution from the manufacturers.
4. This question:
   [How can I make the function keys the default on a Logitech K760 Bluetooh keyboard?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/326959/how-can-i-make-the-function-keys-the-default-on-a-logitech-k760-bluetooh-keyboar)
   has an answer but it is for a different model, whose solution does
   not work on my model.

If you need further information from my system, don't hesitate to drop a message.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **solaar**, which has a version in Ubuntu's universal repo.

```
sudo apt install solaar
```

Then, you run solaar, it has a nice GUI with instructions, once you connect a Logitech keyboard, it will show you a switch for de Fn key behavior.

[image]

[I've read this post to get the solution](https://www.zdnet.com/article/using-linux-to-manage-my-keyboard-and-mouse-with-logitechs-unifying-receiver/)